# Quiero usar ajax y json para que antes de enviar mi formulario me valide si un campo ya existe en la base de datos?

Tags: python, django

Hola necesito por favor alguien que me ayude a validar, si un campo ya es existente en la base de datos antes de enviar el formulario y si es así me retorne un mensaje y me devuelva al formulario como lo hago?

Mira esta es mi vista que hace el proceso:

```
def inventarioingresoe(request):
    empaque = Empaque.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        variedad = request.POST["variedad"]
        empaque = request.POST["empaque"]
        grado = request.POST["grado"]
        comercializadora = request.POST["comercializadora"]
        ramos = request.POST["ramos"]
        unidades = request.POST["unidades"]
        celda = request.POST["celda"]
        if Empaque.objects.filter(celda=celda):
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'valido': False}))
        else:
            nuevoingreso = Empaque.objects.create( fecha = fecha,
                                                   hora = hora,
                                                   variedad = variedad,
                                                   empaque = empaque,
                                                   grado = grado,
                                                   comercializadora = comercializadora,
                                                   ramos = ramos,
                                                   unidades = unidades,
                                                   total = int(unidades) * int(ramos),
                                                   celda = celda)
            return redirect('empaque')

    return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {})
```

Esta es mi plantilla:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" class="cerrarmodal">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> </i>
    </button>
    <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Ingresar caja</h4>
</div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form class="formatolinea" method="post" name="empaque" id="empaque" action="{% url 'empaqueingreso' %}" onSubmit="return iempaque();">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label>Variedad</label>
                        <select name="variedad" value="{{variedad}}">
                            <option>Seleccione la varieda</option>
                            <option>Freedom</option>
                            <option>Vendela</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="mensaje" id="mensajev" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar la variedad</div>
                        <label>Grado</label>
                        <select name="grado" value='{{grado}}'>
                            <option>Seleccione el grado</option>
                            <option value="40">40</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="60">60</option>
                            <option value="70">70</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajeg" class="mensaje" id="mensajeg" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar el grado</div>
                        <label>Tipo de empaque</label>
                        <select name="empaque" value='{{empaque}}'>
                            <option>Seleccione el empaque</option>
                            <option>Tabaco</option>
                            <option>Full</option>
                            <option>Cuarto</option>
                            <option>Tercio</option>
                            <option>Octavos</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajee" class="mensaje" id="mensajee" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar el empaque</div>
                        <label>Cantidad de ramos</label>
                        <input type="number" name="ramos" value="{{ramos}}" placeholder="Digite los ramos">
                        <div name="mensajer" class="mensaje" id="mensajer" style='display: none;'>Debe digitar el numero de ramos</div>
                        <label>Unidades por ramo</label>
                         <select name="unidades" onChange="otro(this.value);">
                            <option>Unidades por ramo</option>
                            <option>20</option>
                            <option>25</option>
                            <option value="Otro" id="otro">Otro</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajeu" class="mensaje" id="mensajeu" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar las unidades por ramo</div>
                        <label id="digite" style=' display: none; '>Digite la cantidad</label>
                        <input type="number" name="tabaco" id="unidad" style=' display: none; ' onChange="cambiar(this.value);">
                        <label>Comercializadora</label>
                        <select name="comercializadora" value="{{comercializadora}}">
                            <option>Seleccione la comercializadora</option>
                            <option>QU</option>
                            <option>GO</option>
                            <option>FX</option>
                            <option>BG</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajec" class="mensaje" id="mensajec" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar la comercializadora</div>
                        <label>Numero de celda</label>
                        <input type="number" name="celda">
                        <div name="mensajecd" class="mensaje" id="mensajecd" style='display: none;'>Debe digitar el numero de celda</div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        {%if mensaje %}
                        alert('{{mensaje}}')
                        document.empaque.celda.focus()
                        {% endif %}
                        </script>
                        <button class="guardar" type="submit" onclick="iempaque()"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                        <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.containerfluid -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero es que antes de enviar el formulario , con ajax y json me valide en la base de datos si la celda ya existe y si es así no me redireccione a otra pagina si no que me mantenga en la misma y me muestre el mensaje.

Eso es lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1):

No eres demasiado concreto en lo que pides... pero quizas pueda servirte esto...

index.js

```
...
$('#id_formulario').submit(function (event) {
    var form_valido;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tu_url_para_validar_el_campo/',
        data: {'nombre_campo': valor_campo, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('csrfmiddlewaretoken').val()},
        // la verdad no recuerdo el nombre de el input con el token, pero verificalo
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['valido'] == true) {
                form_valido = true;
            } else {
                form_valido = false;
            }
        }
    })

    if (form_valido) {
        return true;
    }

    // aqui puedes poner los errores, ya sea por clases a tu campo, o un alert, por ahora pondre un alert
    alert("El campo tiene un error");
    return false;
})
...
```

en la vista que controla la url anterior, views.py

```
...
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
def valida_mi_campo(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       try:
           Model.objects.get(id=request.POST['nombre_campo']) # el mismo string que pusiste en la data del AJAX
           return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'valido': False}), content_type='application/javascript')
       except Model.DoesNotExist:
           return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'valido': True}), content_type='application/javascript')
...
```

debo resaltar que de esta forma aun asi se te recargará la pagina, lo cual ya estarias haciendo el trabajo que hacen los formularios de django por ti... este codigo está con malas practicas, lo mejor seria usar formularios de django para validar los campos, y no por el diccionario de 'request.POST'... espero poder haberte ayudado, cualquier duda comenta :D

Comment: Lo que quiero es validar si el campo ya existe sin necesidad de recargar la pagina, si el código existe entonces no me deje enviar.

Comment: lo que tienes que hacer es que luego de el alert poner un `return false;` o un `event.preventDefault();` con cualquiera de los dos bastaria para que la pagina no se recargue :D, ya hice la corrección

Comment: Hola ya me valida la información pero no me muestra el mensaje con el error, podrías ayudarme.

Comment: Para que te muestre el mensaje, tambien debes mandarlo desde el servidor, en el diccionario donde envias si es valido o no, puede quedar `{'valido': False, 'message': 'Este campo es obligatorio'}`, y en el javascript, puedes preguntar por `data['message']` y usarlo como quieras, como para introducirlo en una etiqueta `<span>` y que el usuario lo vea, o en un simple `alert(data['message']);`... :D

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien me podrías ayudar con un ejemplo mas detallado.

Comment: Ya te agregue mas información para ver si me puedes ayudar gracias.

Comment: si quieres puedes contactarme via mail (german.alzate970814@gmail.com) con gusto te ayudare mas extensamente, pero basicamente el mensaje que necesitas lo debes enviar por la respuesta de json, en el mismo diccionario donde envias la variable 'valido',  luego en la funcion succes de el ajax, es que debes pregunta por `data['message']` y mostrarlo en un alert... recuerda que para trabajar asi, debes usar JQuery que seria lo mas facil

Answer (score -1):

Yo usaría jquery-validation,  puedes hacer exactamente eso aparte de validar tamaños etc etc,

Sería algo así,  revisa la doc oficial

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "/check-email",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```