# Quiero validar con ajax y json en Django , un campo si ya existe antes de hacer submit?

Tags: python, ajax, json, django, python-2.7

Esta es la url:

```
url(r'validar/celda', SGregorio_views.validarcelda, name='validarcelda'),
```

Esta es la vista para validar:

```
def validarcelda(request):
    error = ''
    success = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        celda = request.POST.get('celda', None)
        if not celda:
            error = _('La celda ya esta ocupada')
        elif User.objects.filter(celda__exact=celda).exists():
            error = _('La celda ya esta ocupada')
        else:
            success = True
    ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ajax_vars),content_type='application/javascript')
```

Esta es la vista para agregar:

```
def inventarioingresoe(request):
empaque = Empaque.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    variedad = request.POST["variedad"]
    empaque = request.POST["empaque"]
    grado = request.POST["grado"]
    comercializadora = request.POST["comercializadora"]
    ramos = request.POST["ramos"]
    unidades = request.POST["unidades"]
    celda = request.POST["celda"]

    nuevoingreso = Empaque.objects.create( fecha = fecha,
                                               hora = hora,
                                               variedad = variedad,
                                               empaque = empaque,
                                               grado = grado,
                                               comercializadora = comercializadora,
                                               ramos = ramos,
                                               unidades = unidades,
                                               total = int(unidades) * int(ramos),
                                               celda = celda)
    return redirect('empaque')

return render(request,"inventario/empaque/ingresoe.html", {})
```

Este es la plantilla:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" class="cerrarmodal">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> </i>
    </button>
    <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Ingresar caja</h4>
</div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="formatolinea" method="post" name="empaque" id="empaque" action="{% url 'empaqueingreso' %}" onSubmit="return iempaque();">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label>Variedad</label>
        <select name="variedad" value="{{variedad}}">
            <option>Seleccione la varieda</option>
            <option>Freedom</option>
            <option>Vendela</option>
        </select>
        <div class="mensaje" id="mensajev" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar la variedad</div>
        <label>Grado</label>
        <select name="grado" value='{{grado}}'>
            <option>Seleccione el grado</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="60">60</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
        </select>
        <div name="mensajeg" class="mensaje" id="mensajeg" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar el grado</div>
        <label>Tipo de empaque</label>
        <select name="empaque" value='{{empaque}}'>
            <option>Seleccione el empaque</option>
            <option>Tabaco</option>
            <option>Full</option>
            <option>Cuarto</option>
            <option>Tercio</option>
            <option>Octavos</option>
        </select>
        <div name="mensajee" class="mensaje" id="mensajee" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar el empaque</div>
        <label>Cantidad de ramos</label>
        <input type="number" name="ramos" value="{{ramos}}" placeholder="Digite los ramos">
        <div name="mensajer" class="mensaje" id="mensajer" style='display: none;'>Debe digitar el numero de ramos</div>
        <label>Unidades por ramo</label>
        <select name="unidades" onChange="otro(this.value);">
            <option>Unidades por ramo</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option value="Otro" id="otro">Otro</option>
        </select>
        <div name="mensajeu" class="mensaje" id="mensajeu" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar las unidades por ramo</div>
        <label id="digite" style=' display: none; '>Digite la cantidad</label>
        <input type="number" name="tabaco" id="unidad" style=' display: none; ' onChange="cambiar(this.value);">
        <label>Comercializadora</label>
        <select name="comercializadora" value="{{comercializadora}}">
            <option>Seleccione la comercializadora</option>
            <option>QU</option>
            <option>GO</option>
            <option>FX</option>
            <option>BG</option>
        </select>
        <div name="mensajec" class="mensaje" id="mensajec" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar la comercializadora</div>
        <label>Numero de celda</label>
        <input type="number" name="celda">
        <div name="mensajecd" class="mensaje" id="mensajecd" style='display: none;'>Debe digitar el numero de celda</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'validarcelda' %}",
               data: {'celda': $('#celda').val(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
               dataType: "text",
               success: function(response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response);
                      if (response.success){
                          return true;
                      }
                      else{
                          alert(response.error);
                          event.preventDefault();
                          return false                          
                      }
                },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
                }
          }); 
        </script>
        <button class="guardar" type="submit" onclick="iempaque()"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
        <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que tienes un formulario con un action a una url, y el ajax con url difrente, por lo que supongo que tu vista de validacion es la ultima que pones a la que apunta la peticion de AJAX, lo primero que veo, es que deberias retornar una respuesta de tipo json, porque estas retornando un html...

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ajax_vars), content_type='application/json')
```

asi tu javascript funcionara, te recomiento que cuando la respuesta retorne que no está valido, evita recargar la pagina...

```
event.preventDefault(); # luego de response.error
```

en esta pregunta no especificaste que querias hacer, no diste mucho detalle... sin embargo ya hay una pregunta asi... [Quiero usar ajax y json para que antes de enviar mi formulario me valide si un campo ya existe en la base de datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25556/quiero-usar-ajax-y-json-para-que-antes-de-enviar-mi-formulario-me-valide-si-un-c)

en tu funcion de ajax...

```
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "{% url auth_validate %}",
           data: {'celda': $('#celda').val(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
           dataType: "text",
           success: function(response) {
                  // response, es el diccionario que envias desde python
                  if (response['valido']){
                      return true; // esto quiere decir que el formulario se enviara correctamente para guardar los datos en la base de datos
                  } else{ // si no enviamos desde el servidor que la respuesta está valida, entra aca
                      alert('El campo ya existe en la base de datos');
                      event.preventDefault(); // este event, se supone es el que viene cuando haces $('form').submit(function(**event**){/*... aqui se supone va el codigo que estoy escribiendo ...*/})
                      return false;
                  }
            }
      });
```

en la vista a la cual apunta la url `{% url "auth_validate" %}` (porque en esa url es que estas enviando el ajax, eso quiere decir que la vista que controle esa url sera la encargada de decirte si el campo esta lleno o no)

```
def auth_validate_view(request): # pdt: no se porque le pusiste asi
     if request.method == 'POST': # tambien puedes usar, if request.is_ajax
          try:
               Empaque.objects.get(celda=request.POST['celda']) # si te fijas aqui, solo hay un campo que enviamos en el parametro data de la peticion ajax, y tiene el mismo nombre que pusimos allá
               # si lo quieres hacer con filter, solo seria hacer asi, Empaque.objects.filter(celda=request.POST['celda']).exists(), si retorna true, entonces existe, de lo cotrario no existe y puedes crearlo
               valido = False # como si existe porque no tiro ningun error, entonces NO está válido
          except Empaque.DoesNotExist:
               #si arroja un error quiere decir que no encontro nada en la base de datos, por lo cual si se puede guardar...
               valido = True
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'valido': valido}), content_type='application/json') # se empaqueta la respuesta en forma de json, y se envia, para que el front la reciba como JSON
```

Comment: Hola se que ya existe esa pregunta yo la hice, pero esa función no me ayude mucho, podrías ayudarme dándome en mas detalle todo el código completo gracias.

Comment: Y Si cambio el return por eso ya no me carga mi formulario html

Comment: @AngieLizethSantiagoPiñeros he editado la respuesta, dime si te sirve, si no entiendes algo solo comenta ;)

Comment: la respuesta está pensada, sabiendo que tienes 2 vistas distintas, una con la cual haces el render de tu formulario y subes todo si está correcto, y otra que fue la que te puse de ejemplo para que valides si el campo existe en la base de datos... serian 2 vistas 2 urls

Comment: Y si esta función la tengo a parte de mi plantilla, es decir en otro archivo como la llamo en la plantilla.

Comment: Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Mira me sale este error.

Comment: csrf verification failed. request aborted Y tambien me sale este otro error.

Comment: No me esta haciendo la validación me agrega el empaque como se nada

Comment: o sea, el token, debes reemplazar eso que pusiste, (yo copie y pegue lo que pusiste), por `$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()`... para el error de reverse with arguments ()... debes agregar una nueva vista con la función que te di, y al momento de crear la url con el nombre, debe tener el mismo nombre de la url donde estas haciendo el ajax, en la parte que dice `url: {% url "aqui va el nombre de la url que creaste para la vista que valida el campo" %}`

Comment: @AngieLizethSantiagoPiñeros asegurate que tu url de ajax esté haciendo la peticion a esa pagina... si quieres para que no recargue, haz que la funcion `onSubmit()` siempre retorne falso, y solo retorne verdadero si la validacion de la vista retorna verdadero

Comment: No me funciona ya no se que hacer

Comment: puedes actualizar la pregunta con el codigo que tienes actualmente? asi puedo ver bien si algo mas está fallando

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta con lo que tengo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46313/discussion-between-german-alzate-martinez-and-angie-lizeth-santiago-pineros).